# Laravel email messed up

Tags: laravel, smtp

I am using the default email template, and there is are cases that the email is gibberish/messed up.

Additional information on the problem:

- Occur when viewing in IOs app mail (rarely to a person)
- Opening the mail in gmail gives no problem
- using SMTP

[image: vel]

Question is, what can I do to fix this problem and make sure it does not happen again. Whether changes in SMTP setting etc?

As per the code:

```
<?php

namespace Framework\Notifications\User;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class AuthenticationLink extends Notification// implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $name;
    protected $link;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($name, $link)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->link = $link;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->subject(__('mail/authentication.System Authentication'))
                    ->greeting(__('mail/default.Hello').' '.$this->name)
                    ->line(__('mail/authentication.Please click the link below to confirm your email and begin using System'))
                    ->action(__('default.Confirm'), $this->link);
    }
```

I have been looking through google search and asking help in Laravel Discord and Laravel FB Group. Still nothing at the moment.

Any help will do. Thank you very much.

Comment: so the issue you facing is in view point right. then why not make your own design and pass that view to mail

Comment: @KaranSadana, Problem occurs when being viewed in an IOs mail app but quite rare. Please re-read the question again.

Comment: same am saying you are facing issue in view point. simple make a markdown and design and give css as you want in mobile or in ios app . Perhaps its have different screen size.